# How to open a DXF referenced file with SharpMap?

Tags: c#, sharpmap

I'm working in a viewer map with **Sharpmap** in **C#**. I use FWTools, too.

I need attach a dxf file in my viewer as a reference.

Actually i can attach shapes (shp) files, raster images (ecw, tif) but i can do this with sharpmap, i can't find the way.

Someone can help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for SharpMap, it looks like you can [add simple geometry like lines](http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Add%20a%20primitive%20geometry&referringTitle=How%20to...) and if you don't mind a shameless plug, I wrote a library that can read DXF files ([source](https://github.com/IxMilia/Dxf)) ([NuGet package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/IxMilia.Dxf/)) so you should be able to do something like the following:

```
DxfFile dxf;
using (var stream = new FileStream(@"path\to\file.dxf", FileMode.Open))
{
    dxf = DxfFile.Load(stream);
}

foreach (var entity in dxf.Entities)
{
    switch (entity.EntityType)
    {
        case DxfEntityType.Line:
            var line = (DxfLine)entity;
            // insert code here to add the line to SharpMap using
            // line.P1 and line.P2 as end points
            break;
    }
}
```